# How to plot a line graph with discontinuity data?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've a problem plotting a graph using ggplot2 library in R. 
I have a 'Date' variable containing date of disclosed values 'Rating' for each of the 3 'Brand' brands. The thing is that after an event, the market is only shared by two brands. So, I want to plot lines for before and after this event separately although in the same plot. Is it possible? If I plot everything as is with a smoothing function, the chart gets no sense, so I must leave an hitherto between the two phases, which in the date below is between "16/09/2012" and "18/09/2012" or between the fifth and sixth elements.

```
x <- c("1jan1960", "2jan1960", "31mar1960", "30jul1960")
as.Date(x, "%d%b%Y")
x <- c("10/09/2012", "12/09/2012", "11/09/2012")
as.Date(x, "%d/%m/%Y")

x <- c("12/09/2012", "13/09/2012", "14/09/2012", "15/09/2012","16/09/2012","18/09/2012","19/09/2012","20/09/2012","22/09/2012","23/09/2012")
x <- as.Date(x, "%d/%m/%Y")
y <-c(30,32,33,34,35,45,46,44,46,47)
y2<-c(20,22,23,27,29,55,54,56,54,53)
y3 <- c(10,10,10,7,6,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
data1 <- data.frame(x,y1)
data1$w <-"A"
data2 <- data.frame(x,y2)
data2$w <-"B"
data3 <- data.frame(x,y3)
data3$w <-"C"

colnames(data1)<- c("Date", "Rating", "Brand")
colnames(data2)<- c("Date", "Rating", "Brand")
colnames(data3)<- c("Date", "Rating", "Brand")

data <-rbind(data1,data2,data3)

#Chart
(plot <-ggplot(data, aes(x=Date, 
y=Rating, colour=Brand, group=Brand)) 
+ geom_line(size=.5)
+ geom_smooth(aes(x=Date, y=Rating), 
method="loess", size=3, se=F) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
data$Event <- "Before"
data[data$Date>="2012-09-18",]$Event <- "After"
data$Event <- factor(data$Event, levels=c("Before","After"))
#Chart
ggplot(data,aes(x=Date, y=Rating, colour=Brand, group=Brand))+
 geom_line(size=.5) +
 geom_smooth(aes(x=Date, y=Rating), method="loess", size=1, se=F)+ 
   facet_wrap(~Event, scales="free_x")
```

This adds a new column, `data$Event` which takes on values "Before" before the event and "After" after the event. Then we use facets in ggplot to separate Before and After.

The reason for:

```
data$Event <- factor(data$Event, levels=c("Before","After"))
```

is to create an ordered factor: ggplot wants to plot the facets in alphabetical order (After, then Before), unless we do this.

Answer (score 4):

By way of an alternative, and using @jlhoward's `Event` variable:
Use the interaction between `Brand` and `Event` as the grouping variable, then plot in one panel, showing the discontinuity as a shaded region.

```
data$Event <- "Before"
data[data$Date>="2012-09-18",]$Event <- "After"
data$Event <- factor(data$Event, levels=c("Before","After"))

xmin <- as.Date("16/09/2012", "%d/%m/%Y") # Beginning and end of discontinuity
xmax <- as.Date("18/09/2012", "%d/%m/%Y")
ggplot(data) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = Rating, colour = Brand, group=interaction(Brand, Event)), size = 1) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf), fill = "salmon", alpha = .01)
```

[image]

**Edit**
And now adding `geom_smooth`:

```
ggplot(data) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = Rating, colour = Brand, group = interaction(Brand, Event)), size = .5) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x=Date, y=Rating, colour = Brand, group = interaction(Brand, Event)), method="loess", size=1, se=F) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf), fill = "salmon", alpha = .01)
```

[image]

Comment: I though about that but how do you deal with `geom_smooth(...)`?

Comment: It seems that `geom_smooth` understand a grouping aesthetic. See the edit to my answer. Try it without the grouping aesthetic in `geom_smooth`.